# What is the meaning of this syntax in bash ${variable[*]}:2?

Tags: bash

I read a code of someone in bash, and he writed this line:

```
for f in ${variable[*]}:2
```

Can someone explain what is the meaning of this line? what is the scope of the values that `f` can get?

Comment: That's... really quite buggy. Should be `"${variable[@]:2}"` to do what the author wants.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Can you explain why think so? By the way, ${variable} (Of course, in the case of his code) is a some line from the output of the command `gcc -MM *.c`.

Comment: So, the original code takes the variable `array`, generates a string by concatenating its members with the first character of the variable `IFS` (or a space if IFS is unset), and then splits that string on all characters in IFS, then treats each word as that as a glob and expands those globs, and appends `:2` to the last of those words. I can't see why anyone would *want* that mess of behavior.

Comment: How **exactly** are they assigning to `variable`? Is it `variable=( $(gcc ...) )` (making it an array), or `variable=$(gcc ...)` (making it a string -- which, when expanded as an array, acts like a single-element array, unless further segments are defined somewhere else), or something else?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Like that: `while read -a variable; do` while "variable" is a line from the output of `gcc -MM *.c`

Comment: `${variable[*]}` is useless for a regular string. There's no point to using it whatsoever; it behaves identically to just `$variable` (which itself has side effects due to improper quoting -- should be `"$variable"` to ensure that it's treated as just one word).

Comment: ...which is to say that this doesn't sound like code you should be trying to learn from.

Comment: Oh -- I missed the `-a` in `read -a variable` when I was referring to a "regular string" above. They are genuinely reading into an array, then; but `${variable[*]}` creates a string from that array again (and then does the split and glob operations on that string described above, after which `:2` is appended).

Answer (score 3):

The code given is a buggy attempt to expand an array skipping the first two arguments.

A corrected version would iterate over `"${variable[@]:2}"`, with the quotes (and the `:2` inside the braces rather than outside them), as demonstrated below:

```
variable=( "first argument" "second argument" "third argument" "fourth argument" "fifth argument" )
printf '%s\n' "${variable[@]:2}"
```

...properly emits:

```
third argument
fourth argument
fifth argument
```

---

As it's already written, the code behaves as follows (and the below is not even a worst-case scenario, wherein the string would contain globs):

```
variable=( "first argument" "second argument" "third argument" "fourth argument" "fifth argument" )
printf '%s\n' ${variable[*]}:2  ## THIS IS BUGGY
```

...emits output of:

```
first
argument
second
argument
third
argument
fourth
argument
fifth
argument:2
```

Due to the missing quotes (and the use of `[*]` rather than `[@]`), the individual words aren't kept together; and because the `:2` is outside the curly braces, it's appended to the end of the last word of the result rather than changing how the expansion behaves.

Comment: Re the assertion on the first line of your answer, is it alternately possible that the code given is an attempt to trim the first to characters off each line of input?  If it's a misguided `${variable:2}`, then the `for` loop might be trying to assign each trimmed line of input to `$f` for further processing....  Just a thought.

Comment: That's possible as well. This is marked community wiki for a reason -- feel free to edit. :)